# I am passing an ajax to php with datatype as JSONP,but showing undefined index in php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

On submit button click,
I am passing  a variable to `sendmail.php`.It's showing that contactname is undefined in php.
why is it happening ?

Here is my Code :

```
var name = document.getElementById('stream_cotactname').value;  
alert(name);
$.ajax({
    url: "sendmail.php",
    async: false,
    type:"POST",
   data : "cotactname="+name+"file="  + formdata,
   dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: false,
        processData:false,
          jsonp: "jsoncallback",
    success: function(html){
         alert("Thank you. We will be in touch with you");
    },
    error: function(){
     alert("Thank you. We will be in touch with you");
    }
});
```

My Php File:

```
<?php  
$name =$_POST['cotactname'];die("A".$name);  
 ?>
```

ALL gone well,Thanks.

Now let my introduce my exact code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var formdata = false;
    (function () {

        var input = document.getElementById("uploaded_file");
        formdata = false;
        formdata = new FormData();

        input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {

        var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
          file = this.files[i];
    if (formdata) {
            formdata.append("uploaded_file[]", file);
           }
              }
            }, false);
          }());
        </script>
```

HOw can I get the form data information in php (like we do as $_FILES)

Comment: Where is your php file?

Comment: Your data must be in json format., check `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: why you use jsonp? is this cross domain request?

Comment: yes, its a cross domain request..php file is in the same path that my html(where my ajax is present) is there

Comment: var_dump($_POST) also give error that $_POST[contactname] is not defined

Comment: Are you trying do a cross-domain AJAX call? Meaning, your service is not hosted in your same web application path? Your web-service must support method injection in order to do JSONP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using cross domain call then you can call ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "sendmail.php",
    async: false,
    type:"POST",
   data : {cotactname:name},
   dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    success: function(html){
         alert("Thank you. We will be in touch with you");
    },
    error: function(){
     alert("Thank you. We will be in touch with you");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks...Mine is a cross domain.But the stuff which I missed was the encoding part at the content type . I added   'contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',now its getting in php.

Comment: ! more doubt is that, is it necessary to decode this in php?

Comment: No need to use any decoding technique in php side.

Comment: kk.thanks.One more thing is that I need to send a file to php using form data.How would I do that.I will update my code

Answer (score 0):

try to change your data sending for more https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
data : {cotactname:name},
```

also try to check console for any error is post ok on that file or try with correct path of file

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a string from ajax and getting value of variable.

Try this:

CHANGE

```
data : "cotactname="+name,
```

TO

```
data: {"cotactname" : name},
```